# Pasting ligature codes from MS Word to Kile

Tags: microsoft-word, copy-paste, latex

I have two MS Word documents, both of which read the same except for the formatting. However, when I copy from Doc 1 and paste to Kile, the ligature codes hidden in words ("firing", for instance) are pasted as ligatures ("fi", with "f" and "i" glued together). On the other hand, copying and pasting from Doc 2 to Kile yields correct wording ("f" and "i" are separated). How can I make Doc 1 behave as Doc 2?

I tried a number of fonts for the Docs, but the results are the same. Thanks.

Comment: Word documents have a LOT of Metadata and other hidden information. What are the characteristics of the two documents? Differences?

Comment: To be clear: When you look at the Word docs themselves, ligatures aren't used in either Doc 1 or Doc 2. Is that correct?

Comment: @cnread I see that ligatures are used in Doc 1. Of course, Find-Replace can help me, but I was wondering if another solution was possible.

Answer (score 0):

In Doc 1, select all the text that uses ligatures (e.g., by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), and then open the **Font** dialog box (either by right-clicking and selecting **Font** or by clicking the dialog box launcher in the lower-right corner of the **Font** group on the **Home** tab of the ribbon). On the **Advanced** tab, set the **Ligatures** field to **None**, and click **OK**.

I don't know anything about Kile, but those ligature normally wouldn't be retained across a copy-paste operation. It therefore seems likely to me that the ligatures were manually inserted when the document was created (e.g., by selecting **Symbols** > **More Symbols** in the **Symbols** group on the **Insert** tab), or maybe a PDF document that included ligatures was opened in Word and converted to a .doc/.docx file. In that case, I think your only option is to do a set of find-replace operations.